# Instantiate a byte array given unmanaged pointer and length in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, pointers, interop, unmanaged

I have the pointer to an array that is allocated by a Windows GDI function.

I can copy the data in and out with the Marshal class, but this is very slow for what I need.  How can I set up an array that managed code can get and set to as normal that updates the data at the unmanaged pointer?

Can I do it with C# or do I need to use C++/CLI?

EDIT: The objective is to read and write to an array to update the image from any .NET language, including VB.NET.

Comment: Any type of interop between managed and unmanaged code is going to be slow, by its very nature. Using the `Marshal` class is not known to be particularly "slow", so if this doesn't meet your needs, you probably need to choose another route.

Comment: Not for this.  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/pointerlessimageproc.aspx - apparently using arrays is faster than using pointers in C#.  The difference between this article and my problem is that I cannot allocate the memory myself.

Comment: Your comment to Robert's answer suggests that you're not comfortable with pointers.  Describe the GDI function you are using, surely there's a better way.

Comment: I'm using CreateDIBSection which returns a pointer and then instantiating a GDI+ bitmap using the same memory.  I'm using GDI+ for antialiasing and GDI for speed.  It works well.  I'm just looking to see if I can allow VB.NET into the fun, since right now I can't perform operations on pixels without using C# or C++.  I am fairly comfortable with pointers.  The C# code I wrote to OR two 32-bit fullscreen bitmaps together performs roughly 2.2 times faster than BitBlt's OR.  Anaglyphic stereography on the CPU with barely any overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform pointer operations in C# with `unsafe` sections of code.

[See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure how.  How do you instantiate a `byte[]` that uses the memory given by a pointer?

Comment: You don't.  You instantiate a `Byte *` that uses the memory given by the pointer, and then you index and dereference it using the `[]` operator.

Comment: The problem is, I can't do that from VB.  Maybe I could simulate the array.  Maybe I can't support VB.

Comment: @jnm2: Using the `Marshal` class is the standard way of doing this from VB.NET because VB.NET doesn't directly support pointers or `unsafe` code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
    static void Main() 
    {
        var arr = new byte[3]{1,2,3};
        var ptr = GetArrayPointer(ref arr);
        Console.WriteLine("pointer="+ptr);

        SetValue(ptr, 2, 8);
        PrintArr(arr);
    }

    public static unsafe long GetArrayPointer(ref byte[] array)
    {
        fixed (byte* ptr = array)
        {
            return ((IntPtr)ptr).ToInt64();
        }
    }

    public static unsafe void SetValue(long ptrValue, int index, byte newValue)
    {
        var ptr = new IntPtr(ptrValue);
        byte* byteptr = (byte*)ptr;
        byte* indexedPtr = byteptr + (index * sizeof(byte));
        Console.WriteLine("old value="+(*indexedPtr));
        (*indexedPtr) = newValue;
    }

    public static void PrintArr(byte[] arr){
        for(var i=0;i<arr.Length;i++){
            Console.Write(arr[i] + ",");
        }
    }
}
```